# Send a value from Mainactivity and display the value in another activity

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a simple quiz app and I want to display the score value in another activity(another screen) i.e. when I press the submit button the score activity should open and display the total score.

I have tried using intents but it hasn't worked. I am new at android programming and there could be some silly mistakes.

This is the MainActivity.java file.

```
package com.example.android.conanquiz;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int score = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    //Question 1 Methods
    public void question1_click(View view) {
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.haibara:
                if (checked) {
                    String correct = "Right Answer";
                    display_answer1(correct);
                    score++;
                }
                break;
            default: {
                String wrong = "Wrong Answer" + "\n" + "The right answer is " + getString(R.string.q1_o1);
                display_answer1(wrong);
            }
            break;
        }

    }

    private void display_answer1(String answer) {
        TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer_1);
        quantityTextView.setText(answer);
    }

    //Question 2 Methods
    public void question2_click(View view) {
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.true_op:
                if (checked) {
                    String correct = "Right Answer";
                    display_answer2(correct);
                    score++;
                }
                break;
            default: {
                String wrong = "Wrong Answer" + "\n" + "The right answer is " + getString(R.string.q2_o1);
                display_answer2(wrong);
            }
            break;
        }

    }

    private void display_answer2(String answer) {
        TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer_2);
        quantityTextView.setText(answer);
    }


    //Question 3 Methods
    public void question3_click(View view) {
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.q3_op3:
                if (checked) {
                    String correct = "Right Answer";
                    display_answer3(correct);
                    score++;
                }
                break;
            default: {
                String wrong = "Wrong Answer" + "\n" + "The right answer is " + getString(R.string.q3_o3);
                display_answer3(wrong);
            }
            break;
        }

    }

    private void display_answer3(String answer) {
        TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer_3);
        quantityTextView.setText(answer);
    }


    //Question 4 Methods
    public void question4_click(View view) {
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.q4_op1:
                if (checked) {
                    String correct = "Right Answer";
                    display_answer4(correct);
                    score++;
                }
                break;
            default: {
                String wrong = "Wrong Answer" + "\n" + "The right answer is " + getString(R.string.q4_o1);
                display_answer4(wrong);
            }
            break;
        }

    }

    private void display_answer4(String answer) {
        TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer_4);
        quantityTextView.setText(answer);
    }

    //Question 5 Methods

    public void question5_click(View view) {
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.q5_op3:
                if (checked) {
                    String correct = "Right Answer";
                    display_answer5(correct);
                    score++;
                }
                break;
            default: {
                String wrong = "Wrong Answer" + "\n" + "The right answer is " + getString(R.string.q5_o3);
                display_answer5(wrong);
            }
            break;
        }

    }

    private void display_answer5(String answer) {
        TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer_5);
        quantityTextView.setText(answer);
    }



    //Submit Button
   public void onClickSubmit(View view){
        Intent scoreActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Score.class);
        scoreActivity.putExtra("sendScore", score);
        startActivity(scoreActivity);


    }



}
```

This is the other activity java(Score.java) file

```
package com.example.android.conanquiz;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Score extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_score);

        Intent scoreActivity = getIntent();
        int totalScore = scoreActivity.getIntExtra("sendScore", 0);
        displayScore(totalScore);

    }


    public void displayScore(int score) {
        TextView scoreTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
        scoreTextView.setText(score);
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried printing your score before you create an intent on the submit click and see what is the value.

Comment: You should have to check condition of `getIntent` is null or not, in your case you have to check `if (scoreActivity != null){int totalScore = scoreActivity.getIntExtra("sendScore", 0);
        displayScore(totalScore);}`

Answer (score 0):

> Try to print `score` on button click using log. if score is not null than write below code.
>
> From Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Score.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_SCORE", score);
startActivity(intent);
```

> To Activity

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 int intValue = intent.getIntExtra("EXTRA_SCORE", 0);
```